# How to call an oracle function from php in another file?

Tags: php, oracle, function

Please don't mark it as duplicate as I've tried all the solutions but haven't got what I am actually looking for.

So here is my queries.php

```
class Queries {

public static function getNames($name=":name") {
        $dbUser = "...";
        $dbPass = "...";
        $dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=)))";  
        $conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
        $sql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT NAME FROM USERS GROUP BY NAME");
        oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':name', $name);
        oci_execute($sql);
        $results = array();
        while ( false!==($row=oci_fetch_all($sql)) ) {
            $results[ $row[$name] ] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
}
```

profile.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'NAME');
require_once './pages/header.php';
require_once './queries.php';
$department = Queries::getNames($name);
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="cmxform" id="selectdept" method="POST">
        <legend></legend>
        <label for="department"></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="Id" id="Id">
            <option selected disabled></option>
           <?php

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($department); $i++) {
                echo '<option value="' . $department[$i]['NAME'] . '">' . $department[$i]['NAME'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
           </select>   
    </form> 
            <br>
            <br>

        </div>    
    </div>
</div>

<?php
require_once './pages/footer.php';
?>
```

Here, in the for loop I want to call the function which is in queries.php. This is giving me nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You've made an incorrect assumption about how `oci_fetch_all` works.  Reading the [function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) shows that it requires two parameters, a statement object and an array variable in which to store the result.

It makes no sense to iterate the result as you have because you should only call the function *once* to receive all rows.  As you've written it, PHP will enter an infinite loop since `oci_fetch_all` will never return boolean `false`.

You also haven't included the `:name` placeholder in your SQL query.

The PHP error log should have been full of warnings so, as always, checking that should be your first step in debugging.

```
class Queries {
    public static function getNames($name=":name") {
        $dbUser = "...";
        $dbPass = "...";
        $dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=)))";  
        $conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
        $sql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE NAME = :name GROUP BY NAME");
        oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':name', $name);
        oci_execute($sql);
        $results = array();
        oci_fetch_all($sql, $results, 0, -1, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on resource in /home/web/queries.php:13\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/web/profile.php(17): Queries::getNames(':name')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /home/web/queries.php on line 13

Comment: There is no call to `prepare()` in any code of the questions and answers on this page.

Comment: Check line 13 of `/home/web/queries.php`.  It doesn't appear to be part of the code you've pasted here.

Comment: Line 13 is  $results=array();

Comment: and line 17 in profile.php is the $department = Queries::getNames(':name');   line.

Comment: Your computer disagrees with you.  Double-check that you are accessing the correct files, on the correct machine.  If you're working on a local and remote host, are you sure that your changes have uploaded?

Comment: Yes.. working on a local and remote host.. did a check by making small changes in the front-end.. the files changes are getting reflected.. so yes accessing correct files and the path

Comment: I still have doubt on the way I am calling the method($department= Queries::getAllDepartments(':deptname'); ) there is something wrong in this line maybe

Comment: Again, `getAllDepartments` isn't mentioned anywhere on this page.  Have you renamed the `getNames` method?

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong line of another similar function from my code.. it's $department= Queries::getNames(':name');

Comment: I can't really help you with this level of debugging.  If your machine reports a problem with `prepare()` on line 13, and you don't see a call to prepare on line 13, then you're looking in the wrong place.  Step through your code with your preferred debugger and see what's happening.